# Where is [git pull] pulling from?

Tags: git

I am on branch `tm-skeleton` and executing `git pull` does *something* (technically, it asks for password and I hit `<ctrl-c>` there), but how do I know where is it pulling from? Usually, `[branch "tm-skeleton"]` section in `.git/config` file explains all this (`remote` variable to be precise), but there is no such section for this branch in my config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [`git-pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) manual under `Default Behaviour`? To quote a section:

> Often people use git pull without giving any parameter. Traditionally,
>   this has been equivalent to saying git pull origin. However, when
>   configuration branch.`<name>`.remote is present while on branch ,
>   that value is used instead of origin.
>
> In order to determine what URL to use to fetch from, the value of the
>   configuration remote.`<origin>`.url is consulted and if there is not any
>   such variable, the value on URL: `line in`$GIT_DIR/remotes/`<origin>`
>   file is used.